# How to return value in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want after `keyup` in input if data was `0` return is false if was not false return is true. but in my try always return is true in case `data === 0`:

```
$('input').live('keyup change', function () {
    var result = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'search_customer',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 0) {
                alert('data is 0')
                result = false;
            } else {
                alert('data is not 0')
            }
        }
    })
    //alert(result) this output  always is 'true'
    return result;
})
```

Comment: add this : `success: function (data) {alert(data);` and tell us what is the result

Comment: alert(result) will always return true since .ajax() is async.

Comment: Why would you want to return something here. What is the use of it ? the return value is not going to be handled anywhere. If you want to handle the data, then you could directly call the handler from within the `success` function ....

Answer (score 4):

The `.ajax()` call returns at an arbitrary time in the future. The `keyup` and `change` handlers return (essentially) immediately.

Do the work in your `success` handler. Alternatively, you could set a global (or namespaced global) to the returned value, with the understanding that it would be invalid until the Ajax call completes.

You also need to make sure the data being returned is what you expect it to be, if the `if` statement itself isn't doing what you expect. That's a different issue than the return value from the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you've selected async: false as your answer, but there is a better way - using a callback function.

```
$('input').live('keyup change', function () {

  DoSomething(function(result) {
   // this isn't blocking
  });    

})

function DoSomething(callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'search_customer',
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

          var result = data !== 0;

          if (typeof callback === 'function') {   
            callback(result); 
          }    

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: isn't this the same as writing the data handler inside the success function ? This will just call the function that performs another call on success. what does `this isn't blocking` mean there ? I couldn't figure it out properly.

Comment: A previously accepted answer (that was removed) suggested using async: false, which does block other requests. My answer was in response that that suggestion. And sure, you can write the handler inside this function, if it makes sense. This is a little more modular.