# Why is return function different after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In following code `$('body').delegate('.submit',... passed = search && passed; ...` after click on button in form i have in var `passed` output as `true` in case var `result` in function search is `false` because data is '0'. How can fix it?

```
   function search(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('input').live('keyup change', function () {
           var result = true;
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               url: 'myUrl',
               data: myData,
               async: false,
               cache: false,
               success: function (data) {
                   //in the here data is 0
                   if (data == 0) {
                       alert('data is 0')
                       result = false;
                   } else {
                       alert('data is not 0')
                   }
               }
           })
           alert(result) // Output this alert is 'false' because data is '0'
           return result;
       })
   }
   $('.myclass_1').live('click', search);
   $('.myclass_2').live('keyup change', search);

   $('body').delegate('.submit', 'submit', function () {
       var passed = true;
       //passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
       //passed = required_rediuses() && passed;
       passed = search && passed;
       alert(passed); // This output is always 'true' !!!!!!!!!!!!!?
       if (!passed) {
           $('#loadingDiv, #overlay').hide();
           return false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It is unclear what you are asking. Also, where is the variable `search` declared or set?

Comment: in here `passed = search && passed;` search is same function search.

Comment: That explains it.  You have to actually call the search function with `search(e)`, not just search.

Comment: @jfriend00 that doesn't work either. See my answer and comments. I posted a jsFiddle demonstrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
passed = search && passed;
```

To:

```
passed = search() && passed;
```

---

**Edit**

After careful consideration of what you *seemed* to want your code to do, I rewrote the **logic** of it to this:

```
var searchResult = false;
var search = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myURL',
        data: myData,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == '0') {
                searchResult = false;
            } else {
                searchResult = true;
            }
        }
    });
};

$('.myclass_1').live('click', search);
$('.myclass_2').live('keyup change', search);

$('body').delegate('.submit', 'click', function(e) {
    var passed = true;

    if (!(searchResult && passed)) { // <-- NOTICE THIS
        $('#loadingDiv, #overlay').hide();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Setting a global variable `searchResult` and modifying that in the `search()` function means you don't have to return anything from it. You can now check `searchResult` right in the submit button's click event. You're attaching the `search()` function as the callback to **.myclass_1**'s click event and **.myclass_2**'s keyup and change events, so now the `search()` function will fire and properly set `searchResult` based on the ajax response.

Comment: Yeah, that's because in `search()` you're trying to return a boolean value from within an event procedure.  If you add `return false;` after `e.preventDefault();` then you will see "false" when `alert()` is called.

Comment: Ok, i changed but in here `passed = search() && passed;` alert for var `passed` always is false in case output in function search is true, what do i do?

Comment: The problem is that your code _logic_ is fundamentally wrong. I will try to get it working according to what I _think_ you want it to do.

Comment: How can do this problem? did i wait?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

First, your method `search` sets an additional `.live` handler on `keyup`/etc., which I don't understand. If your goal is to run `search` on those events, don't bind the events in `search` *again*.

Second, what is the `search` variable in the delegate function? Is that supposed to represent the return value of the `search()` function, or is it something else? If it's supposed to be `search()`'s return value, it's not--in order for it to be that you should be setting a global (or namespaced global) as discussed in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281402/how-to-return-value-in-ajax-call).

I'd recommend hitting a few JavaScript and jQuery tutorials before going *too* much further; it will save some time in the long run. Throwing quantities of code at the problem without having a handle on why/how it works is ultimately counterproductive.

Answer (score 0):

```
 passed = search && passed;// this line is missing something
```

it always returns true because you are not testing the return value of search but rather whether it's defined on that scope (in which it is)

try this

```
   $('body').delegate('.submit', 'submit', function (event) /* USE the event obj to pass it to search() */ 
      {
       var passed = true;
       //passed = required_selectbox() && passed;
       //passed = required_rediuses() && passed;
       passed = search(event) && passed;// CHANGES ARE HERE
       alert(passed); // This output is always 'true' !!!!!!!!!!!!!?
       if (!passed) {
           $('#loadingDiv, #overlay').hide();
           return false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: I change but don't work, still output `alert(passed);` is true, !?

Comment: `if (data == 0) {` shoud be `if (data == "0") {`