# Return doesn't work right in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following function, I would like to return false if data = 0 or empty, else return true - and for one input field it works.

However if I have two inputs with `class="myclass_1"` and one has a value and other input doesn't have a value it does not work as expected.

On click on the button in the form using `$('body').delegate('.submit', 'click',...` when I  `alert(searchResult)` output is **true** even though one field was empty

```
var searchResult = false;
var search = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'myURL',
        data: myData,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == '0') {
                searchResult = false;
            } else {
                searchResult = true;
            }
        }
    });
};

$('.myclass_1').live('keyup change', search);

$('body').delegate('.submit', 'click', function(e) {
    var passed = true;
alert(searchResult)// this output is true
    if (!(searchResult && passed)) { // <-- NOTICE THIS
        $('#loadingDiv, #overlay').hide();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried to read your question and understand it, but I couldn't. Try to rewrite it so that it's not a single sentence...

Comment: OMG please proof read your question, it is barely English.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is return function different after click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282009/why-is-return-function-different-after-click)

Comment: Rewrote it to resemble English...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoping I understand your question:

You didn't determine if there is an empty input, searchResult will be true when the last ajax-call was successfull(didn't return 0)

You may store the success of the ajax-calls as data-attribute for every single input, so you will be able to check if the last ajax-call of all input's was successfull:

```
jQuery(
  function($)
  {

    var search = 
          function(e) 
          {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target=$(e.target);
            if(!target.val() 
                || 
                (target.data('oldValue') && target.data('oldValue')==target.val()
              )
          )
          {
            //return here, no need for a request if 
            // the value hasn't change or is empty
            return;
          }
      target.data('oldValue',target.val());
      //reset data-result for the given input
      target.data('result',0);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: myData,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data == '0') {
                target.data('result',0);
            } else {
                target.data('result',1);
            }
        }
    });
};

$('.myclass_1').live('keyup change', search);

$('body')
  .delegate('.submit', 
            'click', 
            function(e) 
            {
              var inputs=$('.myclass_1'),
                  passed=true,
                  searchResult=(
                                inputs
                                  .length
                                  ===
                                 inputs.filter(function()
                                               {
                                                return($(this).data('result')===1);
                                               })
                                  .length
                               );       

    //searchResult will be false if data-result isn't set to 1 in all inputs
    if (!(searchResult && passed)) { 
        $('#loadingDiv, #overlay').hide();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

  }
);
```